# Mapbox Navigation ui

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

Can anyone please let me know how can i import the gradle for (libandroid-navigation-ui), as I am facing in adding the module. What is the gradle for this, I already tried
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.5.0'
but no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these in your build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
```

and compile this :

```
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
```